# How to convert ByteArrayOutputStream to bitmap in java

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, bytearrayoutputstream

I have this response from server:

```
{\"fileName\":\"image_1\",\"size\":99232,\"paramName\":\"attachments\",\"contentType\":\"application\\/octet-stream\",\"content\":\"�PNG\\r\\n\\u001A\\n\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\rIHDR\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000�\\u0000\\u0000\\u0001\\u0002\\b\\u0002\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000�+$e\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0003sBIT\\b\\b\\b�� ...}
```

How can I convert this file to Bitmap ?

Comment: Parse it as JSON, then treat the content as png.

Comment: use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` method

Comment: @pskink can you provide an example?

Comment: https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.graphics.BitmapFactory/decodeByteArray